# Calculate Series in C

Tags: c, series

I wrote a program in C for this series.  but when I enter n = -8 and m = 2 the result is zero.

Why and how can I fix it?

[Series here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifKcE.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    double sum = 0;
    printf("Enter n:\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter m:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);

    for (int i = -10; i <= m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            sum += (pow((i + j), 3) / pow(j,2) );
        }
    }
    printf_s("%f",sum);
}
```

Comment: Your desire output is?

Comment: `j <= n`will always be false when `n=-8`, **sum** will never be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the only expression that modifies the variable named `sum` is inside the inner loop. The loop will execute only if its controlling expression `j <= n` is true.

You initialize `j` with the value of `1`. If you give `n` any value less than `1`, the loop will not execute because `j <= n` would be false.

Since the initial value of the variable `sum` is `0` and the expression that modifies `sum` is not executed, the output is `0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            sum += (pow((i + j), 3) / pow(j,2) );
        }
```

when you are trying to input n=-8 this loop won't work coz `j=1` and condition is set to work until `j<=n`